# Immediate selectors in igraph

Tags: c++, igraph

Igraph contains selector functions for vertices and edges.  I'm not clear on the difference between the standard and "immediate" versions or their usage.  For instance, the standard vertex selector [igraph_vs_vector](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Iterators.html#igraph_vs_vector) appears to load a vector.  The immediate version [igraph_vss_vector](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Iterators.html#igraph_vss_vector) does not. I would appreciate a few examples of usage.  I'm particularly interested in setting properties (say, "friend of bob") of first-order neighbors or a vertex.  Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard selectors take the address of an uninitialized `igraph_vs_t` object and "initialize" them. You need to destroy these later with [`igraph_vs_destroy`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Iterators.html#igraph_vs_destroy) to avoid a memory leak.

Immediate selectors are mostly just a convenience. They *return* an `igraph_vs_t` object on their own, but you are only supposed to pass them into another igraph function (e.g., `igraph_degree`) immediately and not keep them around. In return, you don't have to destroy these with `igraph_vs_destroy`.

So, the bottom line is: if you need to keep a vertex selector around for a longer time, use the standard selectors and make sure that you destroy them. If you only need a vertex selector to pass it straight on to another igraph function, and the selector has an immediate version, you can use that instead and then you don't need to destroy it afterwards.